# system verilog : Overridden members system verilog classes

Tags: class, oop, verilog, system-verilog

```
class my_a;
int member1 = 1;
endclass
class my_ea extends my_a;
int member1 = 2;
endclass
```

Now when I do

```
my_a A;
my_ea EA;
EA =new();
A=EA;
```

`EA = new();` has given handle to object of type `my_ea` to class variable `EA`.
`A=EA;` passes the same handle (pointer value which points to object of `my_ea`) to `A`. So, `A.member1` should refer to value 2.
But it refers to value 1. Why?

Answer (score 0):

So far, System-Verilog does not allow overriding of class variables. Only virtual methods can be overridden.

There is **nothing like virtual for class members**, so parent class can never directly access them. When using ***class_object.member***, the **particular class** is referred to. Henceforth, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redefine an existing member by extending a class. You should use virtual methods to access (get/set) them. For instance, I added "get_member1" function to your code, and it returns 2 when called from a base class handle as you wanted.

```
class my_a;
  int member1 = 1;
  virtual function int get_member1();
    return member1;
  endfunction
endclass

class my_ea extends my_a;
  int member1 = 2;
  virtual function int get_member1();
    return member1;
  endfunction
endclass

module tb;
  initial begin
    my_a A;
    my_ea EA;
    EA =new();
    A=EA;
    $display("%0d", A.get_member1());
  end
endmodule
```

You can similarly define "set_member1(int value)" function and use it to change its value.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `A.member1` should return the original member of its own class. When you are overriding a class members, you are basically hiding the overridden members. Super/base class can never access overridden member in its subclass.

As far as I know, only method identified with `virtual`, `randomize()` function and class `constraint` can be overridden without hiding them from the base class - thus they allow base class to reference to them (polymorphism)

For more info, please find here [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) in section 8.14 Overridden members.